# Powershell excel replace always returns true

Tags: powershell

I've doing a find and replace in a whole bunch of excel files (to update some links that have moved)
I want to track which files had changes made to them however the result of a replace is always true regardless of if the required text was is there. A find like this:
    `$worksheet.UsedRange.Find($Text)`
will either return null if the text being looked for does not exist or an object if it does, but thats significant extra processing I'd prefer to remove given that I have about 1.2million files to check.
Here is my replace code:

```
$found=$false  
$xlCalculationManual = -4135
$excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$excel.visible = $false
$excel.AskToUpdateLinks = $false
$excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$excel.EnableEvents = $false
$workbook=$excel.Workbooks.Open($openfile,0,$false,5,"nopassword","nopassowrd")
$excel.Calculation = $xlCalculationManual
foreach ($worksheet in $workbook.Sheets) 
{
    foreach ($Text in $FindText)
    {
        If ($worksheet.UsedRange.replace($Text,$ReplaceText))
        {
            $found=$true
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thought I might be able to use `$Workbook.saved`  as a means of detecting a change but  performing a replace sets that to False even if there are no resulting changes

Comment: I think you really **do** need to do `$worksheet.UsedRange.Find($Text)` first and if that returns true do the `.Replace` and update your counter or whatever you want to use for keeping track of files you have made changes to.

Comment: Where is $FindText defined?

Comment: $FindText is not within the snipet but it is being populated as an array by a param.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
$worksheet.UsedRange.replace($Text,$ReplaceText)

If ($?)
```

Instead of

```
If ($worksheet.UsedRange.replace($Text,$ReplaceText))
```

OR you could try searching for the text, and confirm that it found something?

Before your if replace option, try (I apologize, but this code is speculation, and may not full fix it. There is an article on this at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel

```
$confirm = $worksheet.Used.Range.find($text)
if ($confirm -ne $null) {
    Echo $true
    $worksheet.UsedRange.replace($Text,$ReplaceText)
    $confirm = $null
}
else{
    echo $false
}
```

Comment: A very reasonable suggestion, however there being no replacements to make does not generate an error.

Comment: Well the command will operate, so that's likely why the if statement doesn't error out. i'm thinking you could search for the text, and have it determine an error or response on that...i added the possible option to the main comment

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Theo is correct on this. I've not found anyway to increase the efficiency by removing the find.
Also it seems that on some files a replace only replaces the first instance and therefore a loop is also required.